# Filter data based on sum of two rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to change values in samples with a total product by rows less than 5 to zero while leave other as is.

**I have tried:**

```
    dat %>%
      group_by(snpID) %>%
      mutate_at(vars(2:6),
                list(~ifelse(sum(.) < 5, 0, .)))
```

**Result:** (sum of both row replaces each row)

```
    dat %>%
      group_by(snpID) %>%
      mutate_at(vars(2:6),
                list(~ifelse(sum(.) < 5, 0, ungroup(.))))
```

**Error:**

> Error in UseMethod("ungroup") : 
>     no applicable method for 'ungroup' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

**Original:**

```
snpID   f1  f2  f3  m1  m2  m3
A_001   2   5   2   0   1   3
A_001   0   3   8   2   5   10
A_002   11  5   12  7   0   2
A_002   2   6   5   14  5   3
```

**What I want:**

```
snpID   f1  f2  f3  m1  m2  m3
A_001   0   5   2   0   1   3
A_001   0   3   8   0   5   10
A_002   11  5   12  7   0   2
A_002   2   6   5   14  5   3
```

Sum of `A_001` in `f1` and `m1` samples < 5 so both rows return with zero value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: imnot sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do. Which rows do you want to folter on? Do the F and M rows need to interact? If f1 in row 1 is 0, why isn't f1 in the bottom row also 0?

Comment: Thank you for helping me with editing the post. F and M columns don't need to interact. I have locus ID which is A_001 and A_002. Just need to filter locus with total depth is less than 5. demarsylvain got the script I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your dataset example, you need to group by `loci` and not `snpID`.

The `ifelse()` you writted should work. Here is an alternative that should work too:

`dat %>% group_by(loci) %>% mutate_at(vars(-loci), list(~replace(., sum(.) < 5, 0)))`

Comment: Thank you for helping with the post editing. I was working on it at the same time as you. I just realised so many errors! But your script works. So thank you so much for helping:)